# XSLT Identity Transformation removes first line of XML and changes idents and newlines

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to make an identity XSLT transformation which just copies all tags from input XML to output XML.

My XSLT template looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="relation"/>
</xsl:stylesheet
```

The problem is that the first line of my XML which is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

is never copied.

Another problem is that this transformation adds several new lines and whitespaces to my XML file.

Is it possible to resolve these issues?

Comment: "*copies all tags*" - does that mean tha tyou **don't** want the text?

Comment: Please provide a sample input file and your expected output file.

Comment: Yes, I dont want to copy text nodes, and actually they do not exist in input file.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are explicitly omitting the XML declaration and indenting the output by using the `xsl:output` element (and its corresponding attributes).

See the spec for more details: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#output

You should also take a look at [whitespace stripping](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) to see how `xsl:strip-space` potentially changes your output.

Also, a more traditional [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If you need to omit comments and processing instructions, you can either override this template or change `node()` to `*|text()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like all the problems are solved except for a one: XSLT transform adds extra blank line in the end of the file, and nothing helps me  in removing it :/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is not possible to **copy** the XML declaration, because the XML parser does not make it available to the XSLT processor.

You wouldn't want to copy the declaration *as is* anyway, because your output may use a different encoding, for example. It's best to provide your own declaration, using the `<xsl:output>` instruction to control its contents.

Note also that an XML declaration is optional - so you actually shouldn't have any problems with your current output.

Answer (score 0):

The failure to copy the XML declaration is because the XML declaration isn't part of the XDM model that the XSLT processor sees - which in turn is because it's information about the lexical representation, which is below the level that XSLT is concerned with.

The extra whitespace is probably because you used indent="yes".